# Moving a Rotated UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

I have a problem. I'm working on making a game. As part of my game I need images to be rotated and then moved in the direction of the rotated angle inside a game loop (using an `NSTimer`). In essence I'm trying to create the effect of launching a projectile. The code works fine when moving in perpendicular directions such as 0, 90, 180, 270, and 360 degrees, but any other angle and the image starts to glitch out. The object on the screen maintains its correct bounds and contents, but the actual displayed image disappears. Does anybody know what the problem is or someway I could get around it? If needed, I can make and post a video of my problem so you can see what I'm talking about.

Here is a sample of the code I'm using. The "background" variable is just a `UIImageView`:

```
angle = 60;
background.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(object.transform, angle*M_PI/180); //converts degrees to radians and rotates the image
background.frame = CGRectMake( background.frame.origin.x + cos(angle*m_PI/180)*32; background.frame.origin.y -sin(angle*M_PI/180)*32, background.frame.size.width, background.frame.size.height); //moves the image in the direction of the angle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, there is a semicolon after the x origin in your `CGRect` instead of a comma. Was that just a typo?

[The `UIView` documentation for `frame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) states:

> Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the
>   value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.
>
> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform
>   property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you
>   can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size
>   using the bounds property instead.

So there you have it, you should not be trying to change the `frame` when setting a custom `transform`. You are only trying to adjust the position of the view anyway so just modify your code to adjust `center` instead of the origin coordinates.

To change the size, you can use the `bounds`.

```
CGRect bounds = myView.bounds;
bounds.size.width = whatever;
bounds.size.height = whatever;
myView.bounds = bounds;
```

Comment: thanks! Setting the center works! I'm a self taught programmer and unfortunately I lack the knowledge of the logistical side of languages. This information will help me enhance my game engine I'm working on!

Comment: One more question. Now that I can no longer alter the frame, how do I resize the view using it's bounds?

Comment: As per the same documentation I posted, use the `bounds`. Editing my answer to include that.